# Vuejs organization for a website

Tags: web, vue.js

First time using Vuejs and have a question about organization.  Building a website pages vary in functionality, one page may have many areas of functionality [modals, forms, pagination, content filtering via ajax]. Would it be best to have a **`new Vue()`** for each page stacking functionality by components or each section of functionality should have it's own **`new Vue()`**.  Some of these sections may need to talk to one another.  My concern is having a main app.js file that is bloated.

Comment: I dont think `new Vue()` is required for every page, you can check [vue-hackernews](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) for model implementation

Comment: Are you building a "single page application", or are you adding Vue to separate, static pages that are controlled/routed by a separate backend technology like Django, Ruby, et al?

Comment: Not a single page app but a website built with Craft CMS.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can just use one `new Vue()` instance for all pages. It does not make sense to have multiple vue instances per page.

As on a page reload the instance is recreated. I guess you don't have a SPA. So you rather have some templates where you have your app container and the vue components there, right?

You can for example create a `components/index.js` where you import / export all your components. So you have an entry for your components. (Cleaner structure)

And in your main.js you simply import them.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Components from './components/'

const app = new Vue({
  components: {...Components }
}).$mount('#app')
```

And your components.js will look like this

```
import Pagination from './components/pagination.vue'
import Modal from '.components/modal.vue'

const Components = {
 Pagination,
 Modal
}

export {...Components }
export default Components
```

You can then import your components as es6 modules

```
import {Modal, Pagination} from './components'
```

Which is a nice way of organizing them if you use them in other components.

However, as you don't use vue-router you can't (at least I don't know any way) use webpacks code splitting to create smaller bundles, depending on their route and components used on that route.

Comment: Yes this is not a SPA but will be using Vuejs for some UI functionality like post filtering & pagination. Which may differ from page to page.  It would be impractical to use it for an entire page in this context.